# Maths in flex: How do i add numbers and display result as a label?

Tags: apache-flex, adobe, flex4.5, flexbuilder

thank you for your time.

I have 2 labels with numerical values i would like to add together.

```
<s:Label id="cost_1" x="261" y="138" text="150" />
<s:Label id="cost_2" x="280" y="138" text="220"/>
<s:Label id="totals" x="291" y="138" text=""/>
```

I need to the third label (id="totals") to visually display the sum of first two labels. (150+220=totals.text)

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lots of ways to do this; but given your code the simplest way would be something like this:

```
<s:Label id="totals" x="291" y="138" text="{int(cost_1.text) + int(cost_2.text)}" />
```

Although the labels may display numeric values; they are actually string values; so this code casts them to ints.  From there, it's just a simple arithmetic operation.

Comment: Thank you! Works like a dream!!